# Convert multiple images to another format/resolution

Tags: batch, adobe-photoshop

In **Adbobe Photoshop CC 2015**, how can I convert multiple images to another format or change their resolution in one step (batch processing), without installing additional plugins?

Answer (score 0):

We're going to do this in three steps:

1. Open all files as layers in one file
2. Specify resolution/format
3. Export them all

The steps to archive this are:

1. Click "File" > "Scripts" > "Load Files into Stack"
2. In the window, add all files/directories to import. **Don't** check the automatic Smart Object conversion. Click "Ok"
3. The script will open each file and copy it as a new layer to the first one. This might take some time, but no manual intervention is required.
4. When the import is done, mark all layers in the "Layers"-Window, Right click and select "Export as..."
5. In the dialog, you can now change the resolution and type for each individual Image, or select all/some images from the list and change multiple images.
6. When you're happy, click "Export all..."
7. Profit!